# Joystick + c# : Analog button

Tags: c#, directx, joystick, gamepad

I am using Microsoft DirectX to get access to my gamepad. This is an usb gamepad like this one:

[image]

I could get access to know when buttons are pressed and also the analog values of the axis...

The thing is if there is a way to know when the analog button is pressed (Red light on).

Is that possible? How?

Comment: What do you mean: *analog button*, are you talking about the triggers L2 / R2, or are you referring to the pressure sensitive face buttons?

Comment: I mean the button that enables the potentiometers for the x,y,z axis. The one that turns on the red light...

Comment: No, this is probably not possible since its not an Input button, its a button that alters the way the hardware works.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend [SlimDX](http://slimdx.org/) or [SharpDX](https://code.google.com/p/sharpdx/source/browse/Samples/DirectInput/JoystickApp/Program.cs?r=c2a5b8e19628866fc4e13df4e18aee701d2e48f1) for your Project. They support the DirectX API and are really simple.

**SlimDX**:

```
using SlimDX.DirectInput;
```

Create a new DirectInput-Object:

```
DirectInput input = new DirectInput();
```

Then a GameController Class for Handling:

```
public class GameController
{
    private Joystick joystick;
    private JoystickState state = new JoystickState();
}
```

And use it like this:

```
public GameController(DirectInput directInput, Game game, int number)
{
    // Search for Device
    var devices = directInput.GetDevices(DeviceClass.GameController, DeviceEnumerationFlags.AttachedOnly);
    if (devices.Count == 0 || devices[number] == null)
    {
        // No Device
        return;
    }

    // Create Gamepad
    joystick = new Joystick(directInput, devices[number].InstanceGuid);  
    joystick.SetCooperativeLevel(game.Window.Handle, CooperativeLevel.Exclusive | CooperativeLevel.Foreground);

    // Set Axis Range for the Analog Sticks between -1000 and 1000 
    foreach (DeviceObjectInstance deviceObject in joystick.GetObjects())
    {
        if ((deviceObject.ObjectType & ObjectDeviceType.Axis) != 0)
            joystick.GetObjectPropertiesById((int)deviceObject.ObjectType).SetRange(-1000, 1000);
    }
    joystick.Acquire();
}
```

Finally get per Method the State:

```
public JoystickState GetState()
{
    if (joystick.Acquire().IsFailure || joystick.Poll().IsFailure)
    {
        state = new JoystickState();
        return state;
    }

    state = joystick.GetCurrentState();

    return state;
}
```

Comment: Yes, i am using something similar in its structure. Just using Microsoft Direct X... Why SLIM/SHARP are better? Could get knowledge of the state of the red light of the gamepad?

Comment: It's a good wrapper and i prefer some features of the Framework. For the Red Light i suggest it will contain in joystick.GetObjects().

Comment: Thanks @Smartis I will check joystick.GetObjects() for that... I need to know if the analog is on in order to know if z axis is available...

Comment: What are Game and number in GameController method for? Game object isn't recognized by VS...

Comment: In this Case it's the Game Object is from XNA and sorry GameController Class will i edit now...